# Pymongo issue in a python project

Tags: python, pymongo

I have installed pymongo, and when I start a new project and I write 
`import pymongo` Python shows me the next error.

Python version: `3.4.3`

**Error code**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestMongoDB.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymongo
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

**Pymongo**

If I put this code 
`python -c "import pymongo; print(pymongo.version); print(pymongo.has_c())"` into the terminal, it shows the next information.

```
3.0rc1
True
```

I'm trying to execute my python code via terminal with this command

`python3 TestMongoDB.py`

**Input**

```
python -c "import pymongo; import sys; print(pymongo.version); print(pymongo.has_c()); print (sys.path)"
```

**Output**

```
3.0rc1
True
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-3.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

**Input python code**

```
# Include mongo library.
import pymongo

# Include sys library.
import sys

print (sys.path)
```

**Output python code**

```
['/Users/ismaelmoral/python/TestMongoDB', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-3.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Add `import sys; print sys.path` to both `TestMongoDB.py` and `python -c ...` . What is the output ?

Comment: I updated the question info @ThePavoIC.

Comment: Add it to `TestMongoDB.py` as well, before `import pymongo` .

Comment: Do you mongo db installed? Which version is it?

Comment: Looks like you install pymongo in python 2, but run your script on python3

Comment: MongoDB is installed in his latest version.

Comment: Updated question with more information about my problem.

Comment: @AlexLisovoy but how can I install pymongo for python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have installed your pymongo for Python 2, but you are trying to run it using Python 3.  You need to install it for Python 3.

You can see that the command that works uses `python` whereas the one that fails uses `python3`.  You can verify that this is the problem by checking that this works:

```
python testMongoDB.py
```

and this fails:

```
python3 -c "import pymongo; print(pymongo.version); print(pymongo.has_c())"
```

#### Solution

I'll assume you use `pip` to install your packages.  You need to use `pip` for your Python 3 installation rather than the one that is on your default path for Python 2.

Go to the directory `\root\dir\for\Python3X\Scripts`.  Run the `pip` that you find in there, e.g. `./pip install pymongo` and that will install it for Python 3

If that solution doesn't meet your needs - have a look at the [Pymongo installation docs](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html).